# Ember Store Push to Model within Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a relationship setup between my models like so...

```
A {
 a1: undefined,
 a2: undefined,
 B: {
    Cs: [{}],
    Ds: []
 }
```

A contains basic attributes, and has a model B that belongsTo it. Model B hasMany Cs and hasMany Ds.

Typically you push to the store doing something like this, and it would update the model A in store to have a1 = 'blue'.

```
store.push({
  id: 0,
  type: 'A',
  a1: 'blue'
}
```

How can I push to the store to update a specific item in Cs, or Ds?

Answer (score 0):

Every `C` or `D` has a unique `id`.
This is a requirement by `ember-data`.
So you can do something like:

```
store.push({
  id: 'unique_id_of_c',
  type: 'C',
  attributes: {...}
});
```

Comment: Hm, well there is an issue with that. I can't keep track of all C's because there is a large amount of them. I was trying to limit each A to having two Cs. As data for A.B.C1 came in I would replace the data in row 0 for A.B.C1. When data for A.B.C2 came in I would just replace the data in row 0 for A.B.C2. So row 0 in the respective C is always replaced. Am I just better off getting rid of Model C, and moving it into A?